# Is there a way to add multiple variables together without implicitly declaration

Tags: c#, variables, calculation

I have 23 int variables that get assigned value upon form load, is there a shortcut to add them together without implicit addition. 
I.E VarAns = Var1 + Var2 + Var3.... + Var 23.

```
 MathsGrp1 = Convert.ToInt32(textBoxMathsGrp1.Text);
        MathsGrp3 = Convert.ToInt32(textBoxMathsGrp3.Text);
        MathsGrp2 = Convert.ToInt32(textBoxMathsGrp2.Text);
        MathsGrp4 = Convert.ToInt32(textBoxMathsGrp4.Text);
        EnglishGrp1 = Convert.ToInt32(textBoxEnglishGrp1.Text);
        EnglishGrp2 = Convert.ToInt32(textBoxEnglishGrp3.Text);
        EnglishGrp3 = Convert.ToInt32(textBoxEnglishGrp2.Text);
        EnglishGrp4 = Convert.ToInt32(textBoxEnglishGrp4.Text);
        Construction = Convert.ToInt32(textBoxConstruction.Text);
        PSD = Convert.ToInt32(textBoxPSD.Text);
        Careers = Convert.ToInt32(textBoxCareers.Text);
        ASDAN = Convert.ToInt32(textBoxASDAN.Text);
        Music = Convert.ToInt32(textBoxMusic.Text);
        Spare = Convert.ToInt32(textBoxSpare.Text);
        Art = Convert.ToInt32(textBoxArt.Text);
        Science = Convert.ToInt32(textBoxScience.Text);
        PEGrp1 = Convert.ToInt32(textBoxPEGrp1.Text);
        PEGrp2 = Convert.ToInt32(textBoxPEGrp2.Text);
        ICT = Convert.ToInt32(textBoxICT.Text);
        HairDressing = Convert.ToInt32(textBoxHairDressing.Text);
        CookingGrp1 = Convert.ToInt32(textBoxCookingGrp1.Text);
        CookingGrp2 = Convert.ToInt32(textBoxCookingGrp2.Text);
        CookingGrp3 = Convert.ToInt32(textBoxCookingGrp3.Text);
        // int Check =  insert Long list of variables here
```

P.S i know theres a better way to initilise and convert the textbox strings into integers but i want to keep it simple.

Comment: Consider using a collection.

Comment: There is no "shortcut" for addition, `A + B` is as short as it gets.  What are you trying to do?  If you want to sum them all together, then you'll have to sum them.  You could put them in an array and then sum the array, but that hardly qualifies as a "shortcut".

Comment: i need to validate that all the input gathered from all the textboxes = 50.
else while loops futher down get stuck.
My solution is an if statement over the while loop, that catch if 50 isnt reached, but to do that, i need to add everything together.

Comment: Are you using web forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public void Function()
  {
     List<int> Collection = new List<int>();
     Collection.Add(1);
     Collection.Add(2);
     Collection.Add(3);
     Collection.Add(7);
     Collection.Add(9);
     Collection.Add(5);
     Collection.Add(25);

     foreach (int Elem in Collection)
     {
        int Result = 0;
        Result = Result + Elem;
     }
  }
```